# Restrict variable declaration to module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Suppose I write in one module

```
declare global {
   var SomeVar: {};
}
```

Now any module can use 'SomeVar' global variable.
I would like to restrict the typing only to the current file.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are within a module, you can use:

```
declare var SomeVar: {};
```

And `SomeVar` will only be available within that module/file.

> I need to reference something global that is not from my module.

As you can see from the below example, taken from some module, you can use both `SomeVarA` and `SomeVarB` within the module.

```
declare global {
    var SomeVarA: {};
}

declare var SomeVarB: {};

const a = SomeVarA;
const b = SomeVarB;
```

Both of these declarations can represent a global variable, the only difference is that `SomeVarB` is *not* visible to any other modules in your program, whereas `SomeVarA` is.

For example, in another module the following happens...

```
// OK
const a = SomeVarA;

// Cannot find name 'SomeVarB'. Did you mean 'SomeVarA'?
const b = SomeVarB;
```

Comment: I need to reference something global that is not from my module.

Comment: Hi @NN_ I have added an expanded explanation to cover that.